# Program randomly Restarts

Tags: python

I wrote this small program to generate words and then prompt the user for input to type the word back. Every so often, the program will randomly prompt the user for the input from line 7 (screenshot) while in the loop on line 22. Any idea why this would occur?

Here is my code, word_list is another python file with words in a list called words.

[image: randomly prompt the user for the input]

```
from word_list import words
import random
import time

order = []

rand = input('random words? y/n ')
if rand == 'y':
    i = 0
    while i < len(words):
        i = random.randint(1, len(words))
        if i not in order:
            order.append(i)
            i += 1
elif rand == 'n':
    order = [i for i in range(len(words))]

start = time.perf_counter()

word_count = words_wrong = words_correct = 0
word = ''
for i in order:
    attempt = 0
    if word == '0':
        break
    while word != words[i] and word != '0':
        attempt += 1
        print(words[i])
        word = input()
        print('-'*20)
    if attempt == 1:
        words_correct += 1
    else: 
        words_wrong += 1
    word_count += 1

stop = time.perf_counter()
total_time = (stop - start) / 60

print('======= Stats =======')
print('Total words:      {}'.format(word_count))
print('Total errors:     {}'.format(words_wrong))
print('Accuracy:         {:.3f}'.format(words_correct/ word_count))
print('Total time:       {:.3f}'.format(total_time) + ' miutes')
print('Words per Minute: {:.3f}'.format(words_correct/total_time))
```

Comment: stackoverflow doesn't numbering lines - which like is 22 ?

Comment: sorry, the for loop after word = ' '. Starts with "for i in order:"

Comment: Your first `while` loop looks wrong. You seem to be trying to use `i` to mean two different things simultaneously.

Comment: But I can't see any way in this code that `random words? y/n` could be printed multiple times (assuming that `words` itself does not include that string). I suspect the reason for that is something you're not showing us.

Comment: Ahh thanks! That's the whole code. I can post the world_list.py file if that would help, but it's just a comma separate listed of ~1000 words. I'm executing it from my terminal and running on Elementary OS if that matters.

Comment: @Dude_Scott as a side note in the block where you select the random order, you might want to use a lower bound of 0 so you can also hit the first word in the list: `random.randint(0, len(words))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through python via indexers like that, use either of the following (where i is the index):

> for i, e in enumerate(order):

Where you need to define two variables and i is the index, e is the element.

Or:

> for i in range(0, len(order)):

Where, you don't need to use e, but it's a bit harder to read, and a less pythonic approach

Comment: Order is a list of random integers less than the size of the length of words. Using enumeration would make i start at 0 and increment linearly, which I wouldn’t want for a random word generation. It would be fine if I input n for the first prompt, but not if I put yes. And I don’t see how that would solve the restarting issue